# JQuery's getJSON() not setting Accept header correctly?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, getjson

It looks like people have had issues with Accept headers in the past, but I'm not sure my issue is related.  Using jQuery 1.4.2, I'm having trouble getting JSON with `getJSON()`.  I can watch the request / response in Firebug and it looks like the source of the problem is that the resource in question returns different results depending on the Accept header.  Even though the docs say it should be set, in Firebug it shows up as "*/*" -- obviously, I want "application/json".  Is this a known bug?  Am I supposed to be setting some flag I'm not aware of?

ETA: The request is cross-site, if that matters, but I'm passing a `callback=?` query parameter so JQuery is (successfully!) treating it as JSONP.  The service I'm calling in this particular case supports an accept override query parameter (`&accept=application/json`), so I got it to work manually, but I still consider the header screwup to be strange and was hoping I'd be able to fix it, so I don't run into this again when dealing with a different service that might not be so forgiving.  I don't have an easy way to copy/paste the code from my development environment but here's the gist:

```
$.getJSON(baseURL + "?item=" + itemNum + "&callback=?", function(data){
  console.log(data);
}
```

As you can see, this is not exactly complex, and *should* (I'm 99% sure...) result in an XHR being sent with an Accept header of `application/json`.  Like I said, that's not happening, per Firebug's Net console.  If it matters, this is in Firefox 3.6.8.

ETA Again: For anybody still reading this, yes, it's still happening, and no, I have no idea why.  Like I said, simple getJSON() call, really basic syntax, cross site, treated as JSONP because it includes a callback query parameter.  Still open to suggestions!

Comment: Show us your code and we might help you more.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem in Chrome 8. $.getJSON("url", function (data) {}) is setting the Accept header to */*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not a bug.

Since your call is cross-domain, your browser will not allow you to make XHR calls (same-origin policy).  Internally, jQuery is working around this using the "`<script>` tag hack", to make the cross-domain call (this is the fundemental idea behind the `JSONP` data type).  Since the call is made using the  tag, it is simply not possible for jQuery to modify the `accepts` portion of the header.

jQuery works its magic by hiding these details from you, but unfortunately in this case you seem to be subject to the [Law of Leaky Abstractions](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html).

Comment: Very insightful answer

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code (which might point us to an obvious solution,) can you try using the standard Ajax function and see if you get different results?

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/what.eva',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: '{}',
  success: callbackFunc
});

function callbackFunc(result) {
   alert(result);
}
```

Comment: I've tried what you suggested, replacing my getJSON call (details now listed in the main question) with a $.ajax invocation, and the results are exactly the same.  I figure this has to be a known bug, or maybe it's just that my browser is weird, but this definitely runs counter to expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug which has been closed on the jquery website.

http://dev.jquery.it/ticket/6551

There does not appear to be a fix for this yet.

Comment: Wow, so somebody else has the issue, but they can't reproduce so they closed it?  I'll see if I can contribute to it, somehow...

Comment: In case you're curious: the ticket was resolved, and Pete's answer is the correct one -- even though it *looks* like a "normal" AJAX request (XHR), it's implemented with a dynamic `<script>` tag, which means you're telling the browser "GET this page", which of course it will do with default (`*/*`) ACCEPT headers.So, in short, the hack I have in place is as close as you're going to get to the "right" way. :(