# How to send a correct AJAX JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a form with only 2 inputs. I wanna send a JSON to my POST method. Although, all possibilities give back this error:

```
415 (Unsupported Media Type)
```

I tried used this 3 ajax:

```
        console.log($("#idform").serializeArray());
        console.log($("#idform").serialize());
        var nome = "\"" + $("#idnome").val() + "\"";
        var idade = "\"" + $("#ididade").val() + "\"";
        var all = "{\n"+"\"name\": "+nome+",\n"+
           "\"idade\": "+idade+"\n"+"}";
        console.log(all.toString());
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/DBRest/rest/escreve',
            type : "POST", // type of action POST || GET
            dataType : 'json', // data type
            data : all           
        })
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/DBRest/rest/escreve',
            type : "POST", // type of action POST || GET
            dataType : 'json', // data type
            data : $("#idform").serializeArray()           
        })
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/DBRest/rest/escreve',
            type : "POST", // type of action POST || GET
            dataType : 'json', // data type
            data : $("#idform").serialize()          
        })
```

Here is what I got after printing them on console:

```
nome=yrt&idade=09    //$("#idform").serialize()

{
"name": "yrt",       //all
"idade": "09"
}
```

And `$("#idform").serializeArray()` returned `[("name","yrt"),("idade","09")]`

Comment: Your server is getting data it doesn't expect, and returns a `415`. Without the serverside code, it's impossible to tell why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery ajax rest call - Unsupported Media Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028335/jquery-ajax-rest-call-unsupported-media-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the following

```
contentType: 'application/json'
```

**contentType** is what format you are sending to the server

**dataType** is what format you are expecting back form the server

```
$.ajax({
  url : 'http://localhost:8080/DBRest/rest/escreve',
  type : "POST", // type of action POST || GET
  contentType : 'application/json', // data type
  data : all           
})
```

Comment: Good guess, but how do you know what the server is expecting, the OP hasn't told us what serverside language is being used *(all though I'd guess Java)*

Comment: Good point but does answer his question which was how to send a correct AJAX JSON

Comment: @Zinc thanks a lot for your patience, that was exactly my problem.